# Installation on Google Apps Script Editor (npm install -s node-binance-api)

Tags: google-apps-script, installation

Purpose:

- To do the installation on Google Apps Script Editor. So that...
- I can install npm.

Problem:

- I don't know how to do the installation on Google Apps Script Editor.

I feel this is a very beginner question. But I could not find any solution on the web. Thank you for reading.

[[Console]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33rHY.png)

```js
function myFunction() {
  npm install - s node - binance - api
});
}
```

Comment: In your situation, `node - binance - api` is `node-binance-api`? [Ref](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api) For example, I think that even when you directly copy and paste the script of it, the script doesn't work. Because the script of Node.js is not run with Google Apps Script. I apologize for this. For example, when you want to use Binance API using Google Apps Script, [these threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+Binance+API) are useful? If those were not useful for your situation, I have to apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both Google Apps Scrpt and NodeJS leverage Javascript, they each have services and APIs with implementations unique to their respective platforms.

The only way you can ensure that a NodeJS library will be compatible with Apps Script is if its written in the subset of Javascript supported by Apps Script. Unfortunately that's not the case for the node-binance-api package, it uses a lot of NodeJS specific features. You'd have to do some heavy code refactoring to make it work with Apps Script, assuming you can find analogs for those NodeJS features.

A better approach, in my opinion, is to leverage the Binance REST API directly. You can find documentation for the Binance REST API linked below:

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#introduction

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I'll look into Binance REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install anything on Google Apps Script.
You can use external script with , check if node-binance-api maintainer offers that.

FYI, the error message you see in GAS Execution log means the editor could not save your script because of syntax errors. Which is absolutely normal because you are not writing Javascript.